# How to make the hover class same as the active class

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/outpbj3c/2/

HTML:

```
<ul class="mcd-menu">
    <li>
        <a href=""><strong>Home</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="active"><strong>About us</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""> <strong>About us</strong></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like assistance with two things:

1. How can I center the text vertically which aligns with the arrow
2. How can I make the hover class same as the `active` class

Comment: Delete current hover css and add hover selector to the active class rules

Comment: 2. Change your ".active" to ".active, a:hover"

Comment: 1. Add "top: 9px" to ".mcd-menu li a i, .mcd-menu li a strong, .mcd-menu li a small"

Comment: Maybe consider re-doing that piece of code, its extremely convoluted for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/outpbj3c/3/

Comment: Wow... thank you. Is there any way to stop the shaking when you hover? over `Home` that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of re-writing that CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/outpbj3c/7/ (edited the code)

```
body{
    background: #DEDEDE;
}

ul.mcd-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.mcd-menu li{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background: #FFF;    
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

ul.mcd-menu li a{
    padding: 0px 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #999;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px; 
    transition: color 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 300ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: color 300ms linear;  
}

ul.mcd-menu li a.active, ul.mcd-menu li a:hover{
      border-left: 4px solid #e67e22;
      border-right: 4px solid #e67e22;  
      margin-left: -4px;
      margin-right: -4px;
      color: #e67e22;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.mcd-menu li a.active:before, ul.mcd-menu li a:hover:before{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 42%;
      left: 0;
      border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
      border-top: 5px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;    
}


ul.mcd-menu li a.active:after, ul.mcd-menu li a:hover:after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 42%;
      right: 0;
      border-right: 5px solid #e67e22;
      border-top: 5px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the comments use the same style for both `.active` and `:hover`, so add `.mcd-menu li a:hover`  to the .active style and  give the strong elment `margin-top: 9px;` and you will get what you need, your code should be like this:

```
.mcd-menu li a strong {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 9px;
}
```

And :

```
.mcd-menu li a.active, .mcd-menu li a:hover {
   position: relative;
   color: #e67e22;
   border:0;
   /*border-top: 4px solid #e67e22;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #e67e22;
   margin-top: -4px;*/
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD;

   /* == */
   border-left: 4px solid #e67e22;
   border-right: 4px solid #e67e22;
   margin: 0 -4px;
   /* == */
 }
```

Here's the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/outpbj3c/4/)**.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to avoid the shaking when hovered over home?

Comment: You should at least try and figure it out from here

Comment: I just thought you would know but sounds good. Thank you. I will take a look.